# Authenticate users against active directory on page load MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I apologize if this question has been answered already, but I couldn't find the answer in my search.

I am writing an MVC 4 application that I want to be authenticated on page load against our active directory. I'm trying to figure out the best way of doing this. I am using Visual studio 2015 and developing it with MVC 4.5.2 ...

I was thinking that it might best be done with some angular java script language. If that is the case could someone best describe how that should be done within MVC OR if there is a better method of authenticating users via MVC and AD??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would do this in your controller with C#/.NET, not with Javascript.  Here is the first link I found with the google search "active directory access c#" http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/150854/Accessing-Active-Directory-Objects-via-C-Visual-St

Comment: @Mark Thanks Mark. I'm going to give this a shot! Will keep thread posted on my efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having is that I didn't have the spelling correct in my application for the group in the Domain I was authenticating against.

In my home controller I test my About Method in my action controller with the Authorize function supplied by asp.net [Authorize(Roles= @"DOMAIN\Group")]

e.g

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\Group")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Had to make sure that my application was set to Window Authentication and also in my web.config file

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

This made it work seamlessly with the the Authorize attribute supplied by asp.net.